# How to add wordpress custom HTML to wp_nav_menu?

Tags: html, wordpress, navigation

The default wordpress HTML output for nav 
is ul tag and li tag...

I want to use my custom nav. For example

```
<nav class="nav">

    <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
    <a href="news.html">News</a>
    <a href="departments.html">Departments</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has some default args for the menu that you can change

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
);

     echo wp_nav_menu( $args );

?>
```

In the wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php file you can change even more things. But if you change code in the corefiles than it may be overwritten by future upgrades, so be carefull.